How exactly vertical-align works in a case of image + text? Why is it not precise?


 <img src="https://placehold.co/200" style="  background-color:red;  width:200px; height:200px; vertical-align:top;">
 <span style=" background-color:blue;font-size:36px ; ">Sample Text</span>

<br>
<br>
 <img src="https://placehold.co/200" style="  background-color:red;  width:200px; height:200px; vertical-align:middle;">
 <span style=" background-color:blue;font-size:36px ; ">Sample Text</span>
 
 <br>
 <br>
 <img src="https://placehold.co/200" style="  background-color:red;  width:200px; height:200px; vertical-align:bottom;">
 <span style=" background-color:blue;font-size:36px ; ">Sample Text</span>



How exactly vertical-align in the image block works? To what point exactly is it aligned? In particular, I am asking about top, bottom, and middle alignment of the image, and how the text block responds to that.
Images can express my confusion with alignment better than I can with words, so here they are:
1. Default alignment - image and text aligned to the text baseline
2.1. EXPECTATION - Middle alignment -  Image midpoint is aligned to the baseline (photoshopped)
2.2. REALITY - Middle alignment - Image midpoint aligned to what? How does this even work?
3.1. EXPECTATION - Top alignment - Image's top is aligned to the text box top
3.2. REALITY - Top alignment - Text is one pixel lower than expected, but it's close enough, I guess? Or am I doing something wrong?
4.1. EXPECTATION - Bottom alignment - Image bottom is perfectly alignet with the text box bottom
4.2. REALITY - Bottom alignment - Again, there is one pixel difference, like in Top alignment. Why is this happening?

read the duplicate carefully (no need to delete and repeat the question). You will find the exact definition of "middle" which is not what you think about

Without the CSS code applied to img and span element it's hard to tell. Please add also your CSS. If you haven't applied any styling, also keep in mind that browsers position elements slightly differently. You can google "normalize css" and find what works for you.

@TemaniAfif
Can you stop deleting my posts for no reason? The answers you provided have nothing to do with what I asked.

They are not about precision.
They have vertical-align parameter in the child, not in the parent.


@MarcoSacchi All CSS is inside the HTML I provided, it is a simple example

@TemaniAfif I already read that post like 3 times, it doesn't explain anything at all

Could you add a runnable snippet which shows the problem as I am currently unable to reproduce it.

@AHaworth Sure, done.

"middle" alignment differs from your expectation by half the x-height of the parent, exactly as the third duplicate explains. "top" and "bottom" alignment differs from your expectation because of the difference between the line-height of the span (that which is aligned) and the height of the span's border box (which is the blue background painted area). Try adjusting the line-height of the span to see the discrepancy change.

@Alohci What is the "x-height of the parent" exactly? Is it the height of  ?  is exactly 200 pixels, so there is no difference. I don't understand

You have some misconceptions. You say the vertical-align is in the parent - it is not, the img and span are siblings. x-height isn’t related to body height but is generally defined in relation to the height of the lower case x. Reading the documentation with care should help. MDN is usually a reliable reference and more easily understandable than the standards documentation itself.

@AHaworth I know that the text and the image are siblings. So if the x-height=1/2 of the "x" letter height literally, it means it is 8 pixels. But it's not!!!!!!!!!!! The offset is 5 pixels, not 8 pixels!!!!!!! How does this work?????

Let's take the Arial font on Windows. From the font metrics we get that the x-height is 1062 / 2048 of 1em. So half the x-height is 531 /  2048 of 1em. If 1em is 16px, then the x-height is 4.1484375px, or between 4px and 5px. Other fonts will have different values, but are likely to be similar.

@Alohci What do you mean? The x-height is literally 16 pixels on a screen, I can measure it! Where did you get this 5 px from?

See this diagram on font-metrics from the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontHandling/Tasks/Art/glyph_metrics.gif x-height is not the full 1em.

Note that it is half the x-height of the parent. So it's not the x-height of the 36px font-size given to the span, but the x-height of the 16px font-size given to, in your example, the body element.
